# JavaScript using splice() to sort array resulting in NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort the array according to month. My sample input:

```
var result = [{date: '2017/01/23', total: 364.59999999999997},
{date: '2017/04/07', total: 32.7},
{date: '2017/04/25', total: 42.99999999999999},
{date: '2017/07/01', total: 15.37},
{date: '2017/12/02', total: 33.980000000000004},
{date: '2017/03/26', total: 50.6},
{date: '2017/03/13', total: 65.1},
{date: '2017/10/13', total: 337.5},
{date: '2017/07/09', total: 50.2},
{date: '2017/11/02', total: 75}];
```

What I tried to do is first I extract out the month, then I wanted to sum up the total if they are from the same month.

```
var priceData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

        var str = result[i].date;
        var month = str.substr(5, 2);

        if(month == '01'){ monthIndex = 0;}
        else if(month == '02'){ monthIndex = 1;}
        else if(month == '03'){ monthIndex = 2;}
        else if(month == '04'){ monthIndex = 3;}
        else if(month == '05'){ monthIndex = 4;}
        else if(month == '06'){ monthIndex = 5;}
        else if(month == '07'){ monthIndex = 6;}
        else if(month == '08'){ monthIndex = 7;}
        else if(month == '09'){ monthIndex = 8;}
        else if(month == '10'){ monthIndex = 9;}
        else if(month == '11'){ monthIndex = 10;}
        else if(month == '12'){ monthIndex = 11;}

        if(priceData[monthIndex] == 0){
            priceData.splice(monthIndex, 0, result[i].total);
        }else{
            var amount = priceData[monthIndex];
            var finalizedAmount = amount + result[i].total;
            priceData.splice(monthIndex, amount, finalizedAmount);
        }

        console.log('date ' + result[i].date + ' ' + result[i].total);
    }
```

First, I check if the index of priceData is 0. If it is 0, I simply replace it by using splice(). If not, I get the previous amount, then sum up with the new amount, then replace it. However, with the code above, I am getting output as such:

```
364.59999999999997
0
115.69999999999999
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Comment: `var month = str.substr(5, 2);` seems weird when the string is e.g. `date 2017/04/07`, that would give `20` and not the month.

Comment: @ASDFGerte What do you mean? It is returning the correct month. Start at 5th character then length is 2.

Comment: Is there a typo in the initial data? For example, should `{date: 'date 2017/04/07', total: 32.7}` be `{date: '2017/04/07', total: 32.7}` (remove "date" prefix)?

Comment: Sorry my bad that was a typo because I am copying out the data from console and formulate the array. The problem now is as you can see from the array, there got two April. When I tried to print out the priceData[monthIndex] for second April, it is getting undefined. And thus the NaN when summing up the value

Comment: `priceData.splice(monthIndex, amount, finalizedAmount);` this will delete almost the entire array normally, resulting in `var finalizedAmount = amount + result[i].total;` being `undefined + result[i].total` which is NaN. You probably want `priceData.splice(monthIndex, 1, finalizedAmount);` and also `priceData.splice(monthIndex, 0, result[i].total);`. Why you don't just assign is a different question though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a very good idea to use `splice` to modify elements in this case; A simple index and assignment should be more intuitive to understand; Besides to convert a string *01* to 1, `Number("01")` should do:

```js
var result = [{date: '2017/01/23', total: 364.59999999999997},
{date: '2017/04/07', total: 32.7},
{date: '2017/04/25', total: 42.99999999999999},
{date: '2017/07/01', total: 15.37},
{date: '2017/12/02', total: 33.980000000000004},
{date: '2017/03/26', total: 50.6},
{date: '2017/03/13', total: 65.1},
{date: '2017/10/13', total: 337.5},
{date: '2017/07/09', total: 50.2},
{date: '2017/11/02', total: 75}];


var priceData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

result.forEach(obj => {
  var month = Number(obj.date.substr(5,2));
  priceData[month-1] += obj.total;
})

console.log(priceData);
```

Comment: Hey sorry just a quick check with you, I am encoutering this issue when I tried to run from react native. It managed to sort and sum up the total, however, there is a 0 in front of every number, for instance 0364.59999, 0115.69999. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the number has been converted to strings somewhere. Have you checked the data type of the numbers using `typeof(...)`?

Comment: I used this to check: isNumber = (n) => { return /^-?[\d.]+(?:e-?\d+)?$/.test(n); }  And all of them are returning as true. Oh nevermind, I solved it using extra condition to check if it is 0, then I splice it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your code if you parse the date string into a native date object. You can use the [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) will return an int between 0 and 11 for the month.

Additionally, I used the ES6 [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) function because its 2017 and we don't need to loop to fill an array with zeros :)

Below is my solution to the problem:

```js
const result = [
  {date: '2017/01/23', total: 364.59999999999997},
  {date: '2017/04/07', total: 32.7},
  {date: '2017/04/25', total: 42.99999999999999},
  {date: '2017/07/01', total: 15.37},
  {date: '2017/12/02', total: 33.980000000000004},
  {date: '2017/03/26', total: 50.6},
  {date: '2017/03/13', total: 65.1},
  {date: '2017/10/13', total: 337.5},
  {date: '2017/07/09', total: 50.2},
  {date: '2017/11/02', total: 75}
];


const priceData = new Array(12).fill(0);

result.forEach(o => {
  const monthIndex = new Date(o.date).getMonth();
  priceData[monthIndex] += o.total;
});

console.log(priceData);
```

Comment: @EmmaHannah You're welcome! Also, I want to point out that my solution might yield better results if you don't know the format of the date. For example, the following strings will all work: `2017/11/02`, `2017-11-02`, `2017-11-02T17:55:06.746Z` where the string splitting will not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the sorting of data:

```
var result = [
    {date: '2017/01/23', total: 364.59999999999997},
    {date: '2017/04/07', total: 32.7},
    {date: '2017/04/25', total: 42.99999999999999},
    {date: '2017/07/01', total: 15.37},
    {date: '2017/12/02', total: 33.980000000000004},
    {date: '2017/03/26', total: 50.6},
    {date: '2017/03/13', total: 65.1},
    {date: '2017/10/13', total: 337.5},
    {date: '2017/07/09', total: 50.2},
    {date: '2017/11/02', total: 75}
];

var priceData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

    var str = result[i].date;
    var month = (str.substr(5, 2) - 1);
    priceData[month] += result[i].total;    
}
console.log(priceData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of `Array.prototype.splice()`, the parameter should be `array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)`.  The parameter you passed appears to be `array.splice(idx, oldValue, newValue)`, which is incorrect.

To yield the desired result, replace the second parameter with the value 1.

```js
var result = [{
    date: '2017/01/23',
    total: 364.59999999999997
  },
  {
    date: '2017/04/07',
    total: 32.7
  },
  {
    date: '2017/04/25',
    total: 42.99999999999999
  },
  {
    date: '2017/07/01',
    total: 15.37
  },
  {
    date: '2017/12/02',
    total: 33.980000000000004
  },
  {
    date: '2017/03/26',
    total: 50.6
  },
  {
    date: '2017/03/13',
    total: 65.1
  },
  {
    date: '2017/10/13',
    total: 337.5
  },
  {
    date: '2017/07/09',
    total: 50.2
  },
  {
    date: '2017/11/02',
    total: 75
  }
];

var priceData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

  var str = result[i].date;
  var month = str.substr(5, 2);
  if (month == '01') {
    monthIndex = 0;
  } else if (month == '02') {
    monthIndex = 1;
  } else if (month == '03') {
    monthIndex = 2;
  } else if (month == '04') {
    monthIndex = 3;
  } else if (month == '05') {
    monthIndex = 4;
  } else if (month == '06') {
    monthIndex = 5;
  } else if (month == '07') {
    monthIndex = 6;
  } else if (month == '08') {
    monthIndex = 7;
  } else if (month == '09') {
    monthIndex = 8;
  } else if (month == '10') {
    monthIndex = 9;
  } else if (month == '11') {
    monthIndex = 10;
  } else if (month == '12') {
    monthIndex = 11;
  }

  if (priceData[monthIndex] == 0) {
    priceData.splice(monthIndex, 1, result[i].total);
  } else {
    var amount = priceData[monthIndex];
    var finalizedAmount = amount + result[i].total;
    priceData.splice(monthIndex, 1, finalizedAmount);
  }

  //console.log('date ' + result[i].date + ' ' + result[i].total);
}
priceData.forEach(n => console.log(n));
```

Note that splice() is not efficient if you use it this way (it is not meant to use this way).  Instead, you should simply `priceData[monthIndex] += result[i].total`.